# Deploying typescsipt express server on Heroku

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, heroku, deployment

I am trying to delploy node express server on heroku platform, my project structure looks like this

```
├───build
│   ├───Models
│   │   └───DTOs
│   └───Routes
│       ├───admin
│       ├───auth
│       └───tweet
│           └───utils
├───node_modules
├───public
│   ├───images
│   └───styles
├───src
│   ├───Models
│   │   └───DTOs
│   └───Routes
│       ├───admin
│       ├───auth
│       └───tweet
│           ├───@types
│           └───utils
├───tests
│   └───Routes
│       └───auth
└───views
```

This is my package.json:

```json
{
  "repository": {
    "url": "https://github.com/karafra/repost-data-bez-patosu.git",
    "type": "git"
  },
  "name": "long-tweets",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "Api for matikng longer tweets",
  "main": "index.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "favicon": "0.0.2",
    "firebase": "^8.2.10",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "twitter-api-client": "^1.3.2",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3",
    "uuidv4": "^6.2.6",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@firebase/analytics": "^0.6.4",
    "@firebase/auth": "^0.16.4",
    "@firebase/database": "^0.9.4",
    "@firebase/firestore": "^2.1.7",
    "@firebase/functions": "^0.6.2",
    "@jest/types": "^26.6.2",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "@types/mocha": "^8.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.32",
    "@types/node-fetch": "^2.5.8",
    "@types/serve-favicon": "^2.5.2",
    "firestore-jest-mock": "^0.9.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-junit": "^12.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.3", 
    "supertest": "^6.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ts:watch": "tsc -w",
    "ts:build": "tsc",
    "watch": "concurrently \"npm run ts:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "watch:compile": "tsc -w",
    "serve": "nodemon build/index.js",
    "serve:prod": "node build/index.js",
    "build": "npm run ts:build",
    "start": "npm run build && npm run serve:prod",
    "postinstall": "npm run build",
    "test": "jest --unhandled-rejections=strict --colors --verbose --detectOpenHandles",
    "deploy": "git add . && git commit -m 'Heroku'  && git pull && git push "
  },
  "keywords": [
    "twitter",
    "twitlonger",
    "bot",
    "api"
  ],
  "author": "Karafra",
  "license": "ISC",
  "engines": {
    "node": "v14.9.0"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "strict": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "build",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "types": [
            "node", 
            "jest"
        ],
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types" 
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*.ts",
        "./public"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "./src/public/"
    ]
}
```

Procfile is `web : npm start`, and main index.js file is

```js
import * as path from "path";
import * as express from "express";
import { Application } from "express";
import * as coockieParser from "cookie-parser";
import { authRouter } from "./Routes/auth/AuthResource";
import { tweetRouter } from "./Routes/tweet/TweetResource";
import { adminRouter } from "./Routes/admin/AdminConsoleResource";
import { tweetLongerRouter } from "./Routes/tweet/TweetLongerResource";

// Create express app
const app: Application = express()
// Use cookie parser
app.use(coockieParser())
// Use body parser
app.use(express.json())
// Use template engine 
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', "./views/");
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public/")))
// Binding paths
app.use("/api", tweetLongerRouter)
app.use("/auth", authRouter)
app.use("/api", tweetRouter)
app.use("/admin", adminRouter)
//Define index route

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    if (!(req.query && Object.keys(req.query).length === 0 && req.query.constructor === Object)) {
        res.redirect(307, `/auth/validate/user/?email=${req.query.username}&password=${req.query.password}`)
    } else {
        res.render("signUp");
    }
})
//Get port from environment
const PORT: number = Number(process.env.PORT) || 5000;
//Launch app on port from config file
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(` App is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`)
})
```

When i locally run `heroku local` everything works fine, and app launches without any problem, but when i try to deploy on heroku, build runs fine but deploy fails with `H10` error code. I have tryied moving around dependencies (from devDependecies to dependencies and back), I have tried running different deploy commands found on stackoverflow (hence so many scripts), I have tried removing dotenv.config() calls, deploying using ts-node instead of tsc, removing all enviroment variables and hard-coding them, pushing code with build folder and removing build script. Deploy still fails with same `H10` error  code.

PS.: This are the logs from heroku

```
2021-03-16T22:46:16.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user 
email@email.com
2021-03-16T22:47:33.558208+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 985be468 by user
email@email.com
2021-03-16T22:47:33.558208+00:00 app[api]: Release v50 created by user
email@email.com
2021-03-16T22:47:34.811352+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-03-16T22:47:41.135283+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `: npm start`
2021-03-16T22:47:42.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-03-16T22:47:43.245125+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-03-16T22:47:43.317287+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-03-16T22:48:04.609680+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=myappname.heroku.com request_id=6a7c6999-f493-468d-8d5d-f5654cadcb4c fwd="178.143.32.92" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-16T22:48:05.091732+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=myappname.heroku.com request_id=418ab287-2b9d-4b40-a5e0-806c37bd1c11 fwd="178.143.32.92" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: You could try heroku logs --tail in one command prompt and then run the script in another command prompt. Then you should get more info on errors.

Comment: Yeah, I also already tried that, only new thing I found out, is that it tries to launch app again with npm start. But other than that it is same as logs from the question.

Comment: Its been a while since I used heroku but on package.json perhaps remove the 'npm run build && ' from the start script.

Comment: Didnt help. But thank you, i kind of missed that. No need to run build twice.